# Flask services get stopped causing 502 error on nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, service

I setup my flask for 5 different projects on one server using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) guide

What I found out that once I do server reboot (or once it happens on its own, as I assume) - the project stops working and sends 502 error.

To make it work back, I use:

```
sudo systemctl restart projectname
```

My question is: how can I make sure that it restarts on its own?
Thanks

Comment: Did you miss the `sudo systemctl enable projectname` step? Also running `uwsgi` in [Emperor mode](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html) makes more sense if you are hosting multiple projects.

Comment: @Selcuk wow you are right! I just did the enable command and after it did the server reboot. The project didn't go into 502 error! Thanks! Also thank you for the Emperor mode suggestion - I haven't know about it!